# Why did the CSM have to perform a 180 degree turn in the Apollo missions after stage separation?

Tags: apollo-program, docking

I know it was to dock with the Lunar Module, but why could the parts not be connected from the start to avoid this additional maneuver?

Comment: @RussellBorogove Oops, didn't remember that one, good catch! Some good answers there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This maneuver was called [Transposition, docking, and extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition%2C_docking%2C_and_extraction), or TD&E for short, and the whole reason behind it was so the Saturn V's [Launch Escape System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_escape_system) (LES) didn't have to also provide thrust for the whole configuration, but only for the Command Module (CM) at the top of the stack:

[image: Apollo LES pad abort test with boilerplate crew module]

Edit: Since this is already described in sufficient detail in [Reasons behind the “Transposition, docking and extraction” maneuver](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3995/reasons-behind-the-transposition-docking-and-extraction-maneuver), I'll just post one more video of how [in-flight abort of Apollo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqeJzItldSQ) looked like during the Apollo Launch Abort System Test:

> Unmanned Apollo 'boilerplate' Command Module #22 was launched aboard a
>   Little Joe II booster to test of the dynamics of an in-flight abort.
>   Although the booster unintentionally went out of control and
>   disintegrated - in a spectacular scene eerily reminescent of the
>   Challenger disaster - the Launch Escape System functioned well, and
>   the CM was recovered undamaged.