# What do you call the Apollo LEM plus CM (Command Module) when they are connected?

Tags: apollo-program, terminology, lunar-module

In the question [How far away can spacecraft be seen with an optical telescope?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33385/12102) I used

> ...Apollo 14 CM & LEM and the Saturn IV B..."

for lack of better words. Unlike some people *I (don't) have the best words.*

What is a better way to say "Apollo 14 CM & LEM"? Is there a one word name for those two spacecraft when they are connected, traveling and maneuvering in space together as a single unit?

For example, I think we can say *Soyuz spacecraft* to refer to all three components when they are connected, and *Soyuz capsule* for the unit containing astronauts returning to Earth.

But if I said *Apollo spacecraft* it might refer to either the CM, LEM, or both when connected. I'm looking for a term that refers exclusively to the connected pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen a non-compound name used for the combination; the term "CSM/LM" seems to have been preferred.  Here are a few contemporary NASA sources:

- The **[Docking and Transfer](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/aoh/aoh-v1-2-13-dock.pdf)** (15 April 1969, p. 2.13-3) section of the *SM2A-03-Block II-(1) Apollo Operations Handbook*  refers to them as "the combined CSM/LM".
- **[Apollo 12 (AS-507) Mission Post Launch Mission Operation Report](http://mirror.heroicrelics.org/www.cs.indiana.edu/sudoc/image_30000061709352/30000061709352/pdf/12post.pdf)** (M-932-69-12, 25 November 1969) refers to the combination multiple times as the "CSM/LM".
- **[Mission Operation Report – Apollo 9 (AS-504) Mission](http://webapp1.dlib.indiana.edu/virtual_disk_library/index.cgi/4299975/FID2256/pdf/9pre.pdf)** (M-932-69-09, 18 February 1969) also makes numerous references to "CSM/LM".
- Additional examples of the "CSM/LM" usage can be found in a number of [contemporary NASA reports](http://mirror.heroicrelics.org/www.cs.indiana.edu/sudoc/image_30000061709352/30000061709352/).

Comment: That looks reasonable/useful, thanks!